# Create Rope in Three.js using Physics from Ammo.js or Cannon.js

Tags: three.js, physics, cannon.js, ammo.js

I have been trying to create in three.js a rope hanging from a point using any of the 3D physics libraries (ammo.js, cannon.js), but the only one I have successfully done is with (2D)verlet.js.

I really need and want to create it in 3D because I need two ropes attached to a midpoint so that I can show the instability of the midpoint as a load is applied. Something similar as the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJwtr.jpg)

To be honest, I have not idea how to start, I have some experience with Three.js, but non with ammo.js or cannon.js. So far I have been trying to understand the codes for the examples in these links with not success.

http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/constraints.html

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_physics_rope

I even tried to make a rope using spring function from cannon.js, but you can see that my example is not success.

Can somebody please help me or guide me into the correct way to begin my task?

This is the Code I began to write using Cannon.js:

```
 function initCannon() 
{
     world = new CANNON.World();
     world.gravity.set(.2,-10,.2);
     world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();
     world.solver.iterations = 10;        
        var mass = 1;
        var damping = 1; 
        // STATIC SPHERE
        var sphereShape = new CANNON.Sphere(new CANNON.Vec3(1,1,1));
        mass = 0;
        sphereBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0 });
        sphereBody.addShape(sphereShape);
        sphereBody.position.set(.5,8,.5);
        world.addBody(sphereBody); 
        // DINAMIC SPHERE 1
        var shape = new CANNON.Sphere(new CANNON.Vec3(1,1,1));
        body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 });
            body.addShape(shape);
            body.angularDamping = damping;
            body.position.set(0,8,0); 
            world.addBody(body);            
        // DINAMIC SPHERE 2
        var shape2 = new CANNON.Sphere(new CANNON.Vec3(1,1,1));
        body2 = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 });
            body2.addShape(shape2);
            body2.angularDamping = damping;
            body2.position.set(0,8,0);
            world.addBody(body2);
        // DINAMIC  SPHERE 3
        var shape3 = new CANNON.Sphere(new CANNON.Vec3(1,1,1));
        body3 = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 });
            body3.addShape(shape3);
            body3.angularDamping = damping;
            body3.position.set(0,8,0); 
            world.addBody(body3);                   
        var size = 1;
        var rebote = 1; 
        var spring = new CANNON.Spring(body,sphereBody,{
            localAnchorA: new CANNON.Vec3(0,size,0),localAnchorB: new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,0),
            restLength : 0, stiffness : 50, damping : rebote, });           
        var spring2 = new CANNON.Spring(body2, body,{
            localAnchorA: new CANNON.Vec3(0,size,0),localAnchorB: new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,0),
            restLength : 0, stiffness : 50, damping : rebote, });           
        var spring3 = new CANNON.Spring(body3, body2,{
            localAnchorA: new CANNON.Vec3(0,size,0),localAnchorB: new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,0),
            restLength : 0, stiffness : 50, damping : rebote, });
        world.addEventListener("postStep",function(event){ spring.applyForce(); });
        world.addEventListener("postStep",function(event){ spring2.applyForce(); });
        world.addEventListener("postStep",function(event){ spring3.applyForce(); });    
} 
function initThree() 
{
          scene = new THREE.Scene();                            
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100 );
          camera.position.y = 3;camera.position.z = 15;
          scene.add( camera );
            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
            controls.staticMoving = true;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
            controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];
          var material_wire = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: true } );
        var sphere_size = .8; 
        var segmentos = 5;
        geometry_sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( sphere_size, segmentos, segmentos );
        sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_sphere, material_wire );
        scene.add( sphere );    
        geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( sphere_size, segmentos,segmentos ); // RRT DEFINE TAMANO DE CUBE
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material_wire );
        scene.add( mesh );          
        mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material_wire );
        scene.add( mesh2 );             
        mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material_wire );
        scene.add( mesh3 );     
          renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
          document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}         
      function animate() {
          requestAnimationFrame( animate );
          controls.update();
          updatePhysics();
          render();
      }
      function updatePhysics() {
          // Step the physics world
          world.step(timeStep);
            sphere.position.copy(sphereBody.position);
            mesh.position.copy(body.position); // HACE QUE SE VEA
            mesh2.position.copy(body2.position);
            mesh3.position.copy(body3.position);
      }
      function render() {
          renderer.render( scene, camera );
      }
```

Comment: What I mean is a rope as a group twisted strands. Not a Python function or anything like that. I want to simulate rope, string, cord or catenary lines using Three.js and any of the 3D physics library.